# How does Android handle common library installation used by multiple APKs?

Tags: android

Say I have code in android  package com.mycompany.Client1 and com.mycompany.Client2 and both of these clients are using services defined in com.mycompany.CommonService

I have an option where we could distribute our android application such that apk would contain Client1 only, client2 only or Client1 and Client2

So should one be creating com.mycompany.CommonService as an library and link client1 and client2 to that library?  Or should I be creating three apk and submitting them to market?

But wouldn't I be causing storage bloat on the device because now that library is installed two times if someone buys Client1 (or Client2)  & then purchases Client1+Client2 Is there anyway to get around this?

I don't know details about how an apk is constructed and unpacked on the device and don't know if Android installer is smart enough not to install the CommonService library two times?

-Subodh

Answer (score 1):

The Android install isn't smart enough (nor should it be) to not install the full contents of each app. Each apk/app is its own process and the same 'library' module in both will take up space in each app unless the developer uses a common service apk. It would be up to the developer to use things like PackageManager to find out what other apps are on device and then prompt the user to install them.